# Binding not working for innerHTML in nested component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to come up with a custom select control,

```
<my-select>
   <my-option>Option 1</my-option>
   <my-option>Option 2</my-option>
   ...
</my-select>
```

which works alright with static text. However, if I introduce bindings

```
<my-select>
   <my-option *ngFor="let option of options">{{option}}</my-option>
</my-select>
```

`{{option}}` always renders as empty string (if I replace `{{option}}` with, say `test` then everything is working again). Here are my components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-select',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let option of options">
        {{option.text}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class SelectComponent {
  options: OptionComponent[] = [];
  addOption(option): OptionComponent {
    this.options.push(option);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-option',
  template: `
    <div #wrapper>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class OptionComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper: ElementRef;
  text: string;
  constructor(private select: SelectComponent) { }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
      let text = this.wrapper.nativeElement.innerHTML;
      this.text = text ? text : 'EMPTY';
      this.select.addOption(this);
  }
}
```

How can I get this to work?

EDIT: Almost forgot, [here's a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dnf3L54My4ZcCVWnC5Ul) showing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngAfterContentInit` in your `OptionComponent` before the binding of the view, `{{option}}`, is done.

```
export class OptionComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') 
  wrapper: ElementRef;
  text: string;
  constructor(private select: SelectComponent) { }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      let text = this.wrapper.nativeElement.innerHTML;
      this.text = text ? text : 'EMPTY';
      this.select.addOption(this);
  }
}
```

[**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zeAxTlKcy41OjAhkT7Ck?p=preview)

it's pretty frowned upon to use the `nativeElement` property, A better thing I guess, would be to use `@Input()` on the `OptionComponent`, but that's beyond the scope of your question ;)

Comment: I'd like `<my-option>` to behave like the native `<option>`, for `@Input()` a user of this component has to know that they need to write `<my-option text="foo"></my-option>` instead of `<my-option>foo</my-option>`

Comment: @ThorstenWestheider Sounds reasonable indeed :)

Comment: @ThorstenWestheider I tried to remove the `nativeElement`, but I failed.. I did however came up with a pretty solution for your `select` -> `option` thingy :) [http://plnkr.co/edit/FupYOwHwa9K7jvmGskFJ?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/FupYOwHwa9K7jvmGskFJ?p=preview)